# Android Studio project files not showing up

Tags: android-studio

I have a library project in Android Studio that has been working fine, but today I went to work on it and all of the files are missing except for a few git files. The folders/files are there when I look in the project's folder on my hard drive, they just aren't displaying in Android Studio. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I tried reinstalling and updating Android Studio, but it didn't work. Any ideas as to what is going on here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `Import Project...` and navigate to your project. Select `build.gradle` file.

Be sure to wait for a while, so that android studios can load all your stuff. Sometimes a restart will help, but since you reinstalled it, that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: for some reason, my gradle files kept getting removed from my project even after I added them back in. It is working now, but still don't know why the files were being removed.

Comment: @theDazzler Not too sure either, but glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: Where is Import Project...?

Comment: just try "Import Project" instead of "Start an existing project" also. Because the latter might not work as expected under this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

```
Go to File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules.
```

Click on the green colored + and add new module. select Application module and set the content root to your project module.

Click next and then finish.

This should do the trick and the complete project structure will appear. It worked for me.

Comment: There are no Project Settings in Project Structure unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

I had to `Sync Project with Gradle Files` in Android Studio to get my files back after they disappeared in Android Studio's `Project` window.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
File > Project Structure> click on + > then set it to android
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to:
File  >   Sync Project with Gradle files.
It will show up all the files linked with the gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the IDE configurations by removing the configurations folder manually.

First close your project in Android Studio

In the project's root folder run:

```
rm -r .idea
```

Open your project again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have a slash in the subproject
settings.gradle

As an example, this did not work:

```groovy
include ":somedir/library"
```

But changing it to this fixed it:

```groovy
include ":somedir-library"
project(":somedir-library").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "somedir/library")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of the NDK version

Answer (score 0):

In my case only `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...` works.