# Android Studio Project Files are Missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I was working on app and it was opened in Android Studio. It was all perfect but when after some browsing i clicked on android studio window. it says there are no files opened.

and when I checked in file explorer, all of my project files are removed except .idea folder.I did spend a lot of days on it. I cannot let this happen to me. what possible solutions of this problem?

I tried windows folder recovery, no benefit.

Comment: did you rename your project folder or something like this?

Comment: no did not rename any folder.

Comment: Same happened to me, did you find a solution?

Comment: [Syncing with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774031/1438339) again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`File > Invalidate Caches & Restart` seems to be the solution for most oddities.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before trying any thing. Back-up the project you have.
2. You can look through local history in Android Studio. In Android Studio -> `VCS`(Menu) -> `Local History` -> `show History`
3. Select an early restore point that includes your sources-> right mouse -> `Revet`

strongly I'd recommend you to use `git` to avoid such as situation. The code is `Our Precious` Don't lose it.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a copy of the project and save it to another location and open it from the new location. Build it again and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).